# General approach to reuseing functions/classes in Java

Tags: java

I wrote the class ***GtfReader*** for an older assignment. The class basically reads a special tsv file and sorts the information into classes. So far so good. 
Now the next assignment(already completed) also requires a gtf reader, so I just reused the one from the old assignment.
What bothers me is, **this time I don't need all the information the reader extracts**. I'm wasting memory/performance for stuff I don't use and that could be filtered out from the beginning.

**My question is how can I modify the class/functions to work optimally with both projects ?**
What would be the general approach in such a case ?
My plan was to pass a "mode" parameter to decide if the additional data is needed or not, but I doubts that's good practice.

Here is an example:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> tsv_reader(String gtf_file) {
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
        names.add("gene");
        names.add("transcript");
        try(Stream<String> s = Files.lines(Paths.get(gtf_file))){
            return s
                    .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#") && !names.contains(line.split("\t")[2]))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> StringUtils.substringBetween(
                            line.substring(0, line.indexOf(";")), "\"", "\"")));

        }
}
```

This function extracts all lines of the file, ordered by a unique ID, that is shared by lines of the same group.
Now let's say I want to add a list of IDs to filter by, but in case the list is empty, it should read all lines. 
Again this is just an example. I just want a general approach for these kinds of problems.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Unless you find that you have a performance problem, don't put too much effort into improving performance.

Comment: Generally speaking: There is no general approach to reuse code, only specific ones following broad ideas :-) I always advise to create solutions for every use-case (even if that means writing the same code twice) and *then* refactor common parts into structures that sound sensible to re-use instead of trying to make the perfect solution without any context.

Comment: @tgdavies I would agree with you, but the files I'm working with are quite big. It takes roughly 14 seconds to process 850 MB and a file can have up to 50,000 unique IDs. So I could get a huge performance boost by filtering the 100 or so IDs I need.

Comment: Thank you @Smutje, I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: In this particular case, perhaps pre filtering the file with a tool like grep would help. I agree with @Smutje that the shape of generalisations is usually only obvious once you have written 'the same code' twice. If you want specific advice on improving performance in this case, I would suggest asking another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example, simply add an argument that specifies what you are interested in:

```
// extracted for readability
private static String extractId(String line) {
    String start = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(";"));
    return StringUtils.substringBetween(start, "\"", "\""))
}

public Map<String, List<String>> tsvReader(String gtfFileName, Predicate<String> validIds) {
    Set<String> badKeys = new HashSet<>();
    badKeys.add("gene");
    badKeys.add("transcript");
    try (Stream<String> s = Files.lines(Paths.get(gtfFileName))){
        return s
                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#") 
                           && !badKeys.contains(line.split("\t")[2]
                           && validIds.test(extractId(line)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> extractId(line)));

    }
}
```

To use, simply pass a predicate that will perform additional filters on the ID. Or pass an empty predicate to keep the old non-id-filtering behavior:

```
tsvReader("foo.gtf", id -> Integer.parseInt(id) < 100); // returns 1st 100 ids
tsvReader("foo.gtf", id -> goodIdSet.contains(id)); // using a map
tsvReader("foo.gtf", id -> true); // returns all ids
```

In the general case, making code that works well in one place work well in other places with different requirements is **hard**, and there are both reasons to refactor it to accomodate the new requirements -- and reasons to leave it as-is and simply write new code.

Note that, if you are worried for speed, using streams is not that good of an idea. For example, extracting `ids` just once instead of twice may make a difference in processing times. For non-stream code, you can just keep it in a variable.

For example, single-use code is often clearer and faster than code that accommodates multiple requirements all at once. Trying to refactor wildly differing code-bases to share more things can lead to very strange designs that are harder to code, debug and maintain. See [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Comment: Thank you for going through the effort and rewriting the function. I never worked with Predicate before, but I will look into that and find out how they work.

Comment: You were already using filters, which accept predicates, so I figured they should not look too unfamiliar. Writing this code before lambdas were introduced in Java 8 would have been much uglier.

Comment: Yea they don't seem too complicated. I'll try to follow your rules/guidelines in my next project/assignment. Thanks for your help.^^